# Do these words "Ergänzung" "Hinzufügung" "Zusatz" "Zugabe" and "Zuschlag" fit in these contexts?

Tags: word-usage, difference, synonym

Each one appeared to have the meaning addition, do these words fit in these contexts.

- For example:

  > The addition on the price will decrease our sales.
- Another example:

  > The additions on this app are awesome.
- Third example:

  > Adding  new features is always important.

Comment: I don't think the English is idiomatic. Anyway, without further context: 1.) die Preiserhöhung (if the price is increased), der Preisaufschlag (if something like a fee is added to the price), 2.) die Ergänzungen (probably, more context is needed to be sure), 3.) I don't understand the English sentence.

Comment: @Roland  I have edited the last sentence, it was somehow wrong

Comment: The last sentence is best translated with a zu-infinitive. *Neue Updates hinzu**zu**fügen ist immer wichtig.* But I doubt *adding* is the correct action. It has to be either *installing* or you had to replace *updates* by another noun.

Answer (score 1):

You would use "Zusatz" or "Ergänzung" in this cases. The other words would be used in different contexts. The difference between "Zusatz" and "Ergänzung" in this cases are, that you would use "Ergänzung" when the added information is more essential to the source text.

Comment: You would use neither "Zusatz" nor "Ergänzung" when talking about prices. And you wouldn't use "Zusatz" for adding features either.